# Kotlin application doesn't show my json array

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, kotlin

I just started to learn Kotlin and I have tried to make my first android application with Kotlin.
I have a webservice which built on Restful API and it returns a json array for me like the image below.

[image: Json Array]

My Kotlin code for showing json array via gson library !

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG:String="TipCalculatorActivity"
    var adapter:ArrayAdapter<Category>?=null
    var dsSP: MutableList<Category> = mutableListOf()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        adapter=ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dsSP)
        lvCategory.adapter=adapter
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        var task=CategoryTask()
        task.execute()
    }

    inner class CategoryTask:AsyncTask<Void, Void, MutableList<Category>>() {
        override fun onPostExecute(result: MutableList<Category>?)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            dsSP.clear()
            dsSP.addAll(result!!)
        }
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): MutableList<Category>
        {
            var dsFromServer:MutableList<Category> = mutableListOf()
            try {
                var url:URL=URL("192.168.31.86/shop/api/category")
                var conn: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                conn.requestMethod="GET"
                conn.addRequestProperty("content-type","application/json;charset:UTF-8")
                var isr= InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
                var gson=Gson()
                dsFromServer=gson.fromJson(isr,object:TypeToken<MutableList<Category>>(){}.type)
                isr.close()


            }
            catch (ex:Exception)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace()

            }
            return dsFromServer
        }

        override fun onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute()
            dsSP.clear()
        }


    }

}
```

Of course, I declared all attributes of json array on another class , exactly like webservice

The result has nothing to show. I don't know why.
[image: Nothing but a blank space]

Comment: Well, did `ex.printStackTrace()` get executed instead?

Comment: maybe `gson` can't create a `MutableList` since it is an interface. have you try `List<Category>` because gson support java as well.

Comment: try add `adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of `onPostExecute`

Comment: Or use `adapter.clear(); adapter.addAll(result)` instead

Comment: The program was built successfully via virtual device without errors . So that method doesn't execute ! @cricket_007

Comment: Just because your code builds doesn't mean you won't ever hit a `catch` block or any runtime exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution for my problem . I forgot to add http:// before the link. I just use Logging function and I got a message " no protocol"

Just a newbie mistake. Sorry you guys!